# How to create a String with String.format by taking parameters from a list

Tags: java, string, java-stream, string.format

I want to create a String with String.format like this String.format("Q1={}, Q2={}, Q3={}, Q4={}" list) from the values of a list that contains Integers.

```java
private String createString(Player player){

List<Integer> answers= new ArrayList<>();
    answers.add(player.getQuestion1());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion2());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion3());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion4());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion5());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion6());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion7());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion8());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion9());
    answers.add(player.getQuestion10());
    return String.format("Q1={}, Q2={}, Q3={}, Q4={}, Q5={}, Q6={}, Q7={}, Q8={}, Q9={}, Q10={}", answers.stream().map(a -> a.toString());

}
```

Comment: Can you add more details to the problem, like what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JennisVaishnav please check again I renewed the topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following using `Collectors.joining` with mapping as required witht index and answer :

```
return IntStream.range(0, answers.size())
            .mapToObj(idx -> String.format("Q%s = %s", idx + 1, answers.get(idx)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.format` is not suitable for formatting a list. Usually, `String.join` is more suitable.

First, create a list of strings to be joined by commas:

```
List<String> strings = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, answers.size())
    .mapToObj(x -> "Q" + x + "=" + answers.get(x - 1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, call `String.join`:

```
String result = String.join(", ", strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.format` doesn't work well for this example because you need exactly the amount of placeholders in your format as the list size. You are better off building your own String. But in case you want to stick to `String.format`:

Since `String.format` uses varargs (which is an array), you can simply use `toArray()`. Please note that the placeholders in the format cannot be `{}` but something like `%d`, `%s` and so on

```
return String.format("Q1=%s, Q2=%s, Q3=%s, Q4=%s, Q5=%s, ...", answers.toArray());
```

Comment: `Q1, Q2` is manually appended there, the index of the question.

Comment: The number 1,2,3 in the with `Q` intuitively could be the index of the question.

Comment: Yes, it is. But there are individual getters for each of the 10 questions anyways. If OP wants to hardcode the String, this is the syntactically correct way to pass a list of values to a varargs method.